# Confusion about linearly independent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $K$ be a field an $V$ a vector space. Let $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ be linearly independent vectors in $V$.

Are the following two statements equivalent? If not, why not?

1. for all $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ in $K\setminus\{0\}$ is $\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_iv_i\neq 0$
2. for all $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)^t$ in $K^n\setminus\{0\}$ is $\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_iv_i\neq 0$

Does it make a difference whether we talk about the vector $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)^t$ (2.) or if we look at $a_i$ as elements in $K$ only (1.)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos They are only equivalent because of the overriding assumption that the set is LI. Otherwise (2) is stronger than (1) being equivalent to the set being LI, (whereas (1) is not enough for LI).

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter whether you view the scalars $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ as elements of $K$ or as a vector in $K^n$.

In your second statement the $0$ is the zero vector.

Answer (score 0):

(2) says that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_iv_i\neq 0$ **except** in the case where all the $a_i=0$.

(1) on the other hand only says that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_iv_i\neq 0$ when **all** the $a_i=0$

So (2) always implies (1).

Also (2) is just the definition of the linear independence of the set $\{v_1,\dots, v_n\}$.

If the set $\{v_1,\dots, v_n\}$ is linearly independent, then both (2) and (the "weaker") (1) are both true.

If the set $\{v_1,\dots, v_n\}$ is linearly dependent, then (2) is false. But (1) may be true. For example take the vectors $(1,0), (1,0), (0,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then $a(1,0)+b(1,0)+c(0,1)\not=(0,0)$ for all $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$.